# Trying to create model on page view in Yii

Tags: php, logging, yii

When someone views a page of my site, I'd like to save some information about the visit in my Event table.

At the moment I have this code in my view - but I don't seem to get any data saved to the database -

```
if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
$lview=new Event;
$lview->userid=Yii::app()->user->id;
$lview->type="lview";
$lview->data=$model->id;
$lview->event="view";
$lview->save();
}
```

is it possible/advisable to create objects in this way?

Comment: Views handle presentation, this should be in a controller. The model may have some errors, try a `print_r($lview->errors)` after you save or validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing advisable to do would be to save the data in the controller. For [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

As every view, in the normal process is "rendered" using [`$this->render('view');`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render) anyway, you should do this process of saving before this render call, in the [action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action).

As for the saving issue check the errors using [`$lview->getErrors();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail), and debug from there:

```
public function actionShowSomeView(){
    // initialize your model here

    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        $lview=new Event;
        // assign values to $lview
        if(!$lview->save()){
            CVarDumper::dump($lview->getErrors());;
        }
    }

    // do your other stuff

    $this->render('view');
}
```

Comment: didn't see Ors comment while i was typing